# Can someone explain how I can loop text until and EOF character is entered? Also how to use vectors?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//void FillNames(vector<string> & vecNames);

//void SortNames(vector<string> & vecNames);

int main() {
    string firstName;
    int i = 0;


    cout << "Information:" << endl;
    cout << "EOF character in windows is Control + Z" << endl;
    cout << "and EOF character on Mac is Control + D:" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;

    while (i < 13) {
        cout << "Enter first name only in all caps (example: JOHN)" << endl;
        cout << "Enter EOF character to exit name entry: ";
        cin >> firstName;
        i++;

    }
}
```

Here is a link to what i'm trying to accomplish.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuW9hQPbd1f294dCZN6Q8Ac6lgIy0Ivf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the stream's input state to break the loop when EOF is entered:

```
while (i < 13) {
    cout << "Enter first name only in all caps (example: JOHN)" << endl;
    cout << "Enter EOF character to exit name entry: ";
    if (cin >> firstName)
        i++;
    else
        break;
}
```